# is there any google search keywords api?

Tags: java, api, search, keyword-search

When I search for "google"at google.com a number of related search queries are suggested at the bottom:

no of related links on google.
no of user serching the keyword.
is there any such api is google providing ?

Answer (score 2):

No, google doesn't like when people use automated queries to harvest data. You need to make a harvester and - the best solution - use http proxies for each query, becuase you will be blocked sooner or later by google. You can use Selenium framework to to that. Here's my example (without proxy):

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class SeleniumTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // The Firefox driver supports javascript

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        // ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        // Go to the Google Suggest home page
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

        // Enter the query string "Cheese"
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

        // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("sbqs_c"));

            // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a
            // drop down.
            if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // And now list the suggestions
        List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By
                .className("sbqs_c"));

        for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
            System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
        }

        driver.quit();
    }
```